# A better way to create a pin point on the map

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to create a form where the user can enter the address information.
At the beginning, the form will only shows text-boxes and a map which centers certain point.

When the user enters the information and reopens the form, I want a pin point created to point out that location (if available).

I searched myself and unsure what is best way.

I willing to use Kendo ASP.NET in order to complete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have a database/web service which provides you with geo data, and you look it up using the address your users provide.

To do this you need to add a layer of type `Marker` and bind that to your datasource which supplies coordinates. See [Binding markers to remote data](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/map/remote-markers).

```
@(Html.Kendo().Map()
    .Name("map")
    .Center(30.268107, -97.744821)
    .Zoom(15)
    .Layers(layers =>
    {
        layers.Add()
            .Type(MapLayerType.Tile)
            .UrlTemplate("http://tile2.opencyclemap.org/transport/#= zoom #/#= x #/#= y #.png")
            .Subdomains("a", "b", "c")
            .Attribution("&copy; <a href='http://osm.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap contributors</a>." +
                         "Tiles courtesy of <a href='http://www.opencyclemap.org/'>Andy Allan</a>");

        layers.Add()
            .Type(MapLayerType.Marker)
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Read(read => read.Action("_StoreLocations", "Map"))
            )
            .LocationField("LatLng")
            .TitleField("Title");
    })
)
```

When the user enters his address information you can use an ajax request to call your controller and retrieve the data:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("_StoreLocations", "Map")',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { addressInfo: info },
    success: function (result) {
        $("#map").data("kendoMap").layers[1].dataSource.data(result);
    }
});
```